# Run a python script on a button click in jsp

Tags: javascript, python

I have a requirement where I need to run a python script on a button click and pass the input parameters (depending what option the user selected from the drop-down in the front end) to the python script which will run in a server and return the result if the script ran successfully or not to the webpage.

Achieving to run a script on a button click-should i do it with jsp or java end.
       I tried in java the following code.

```
Process p;
p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python set path=%path%;C://Python27  WEB-INF/hello.py");
```

I get this error.

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Where should I place my python script inside the web project?
(or)
Should I use javascript to run the script.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
     $(document).ready(function () { // Make sure the elements are loaded on           the page
        // Listen for a click event on the button
      $('#Submit').click(favfunct);
     });

     function favfunct(e) {
      $.ajax("WEB-INF/hello.py", {
        cache:false,
   dataType: "script",
   method:"POST",
   async:asynchronous,
    success: function (response) {

         alert ("successfully loaded")
    }
 });
}   

</script>
```

Nothing happens when I submit.
Also could you please give me some pointers in achieving this requirement?

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: This could be as minor as missing a `/` , like this: `p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python set path=%path%;C://Python27  /WEB-INF/hello.py");`